# Python class declarative auto set name based on variable name

Tags: python, django-models, orm

I have been inspired by the Django / SQLalchemy and Peewee ORMs but I can never understand how in a declarative class it managed to take the name of the field as the name of the class called.

Example:

```py
from django.db import models
    
class Musician (models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField (max_length = 50)
     last_name = models.CharField (max_length = 50)
     instrument = models.CharField (max_length = 100)
```

Basically, the **CharField** class will automatically set the `name='first_name'` attribute during initialization

Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python metaclasses. You have a class construction function which looks at all the attributes of the class and then does things (like assigns a name attribute, etc).

First thing I googled that looked good, but search for metaclass or declarative base-class and you'll find more information. It's too much info for a SO answer, in my opinion.

https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/